# Pine Script: How to get OHLC data of specific time?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to get the OHLC data of specific time of the day. Let's say, I want the OHLC of 12 PM everyday, how can I do this in Pine Script ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

(note it wont work on timeframes higher than Daily)

oh, and of course edit `TIMEZONE_OFFSET` based on where you are

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © marketscripters

//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

HOUR_TO_CHECK = 12
TIMEZONE_OFFSET = -4

hourCheck = HOUR_TO_CHECK - TIMEZONE_OFFSET

var float val = na

if hour[1] < hourCheck and hour >= hourCheck
    val := ohlc4

plot(val)
```